# What should I know about near relative calls? (win32, x86 asm)

Tags: assembly, x86

Why are they used to call functions in DLLs?

Why can't I call them using their absolute address?

After all, aren't they all loaded to my 4GB address space?

Comment: Related: [Why do x86 jump/call instructions use relative displacements instead of absolute destinations?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46184755) and [Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](//stackoverflow.com/q/19552158).  You can write `call 0x1234567` and the assembler + linker will work out the right relative encoding to reach that absolute target (in position-dependent code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative calling is used for intra-modular calls, calling direct memory addresses is certainly possible though (this is done with quite a bit with WinAPI functions):

```
FF15 B8401301 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&MSVCR100.printf>] ; \printf - note this calling with a pointer to the abs address stored in the IAT
```

This is mainly due to the fact that windows dlls can't be reallocated (plus they sit in a special address space, as each app has its own 'view' of the system dll's), but user dlls can easily reallocate (especially with ASLR). [see wikipedia's article on this as well.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library#Symbol_resolution_and_binding)

Also, don't confuse indirect symbol table calls(aka inter-modular calls) with purely relative calls. if your calling functions outside of the current module, you'll get a relative call to the absolute address stored in the symbol table:

```
CALL MySymb

MySymb: JMP &MySymbAbs
```

or a better, real-world version:

```
6FC019E9 E8 300D0000  CALL <JMP.&Storm.#501> ; CALL 6FC0271E without name labeling
6FC0271E - FF25 8071C06F  JMP DWORD PTR DS:[<&Storm.#501>] ; Storm.#501
```

All of this pretty much depends on your compiler as well, some my do direct calls to symbols for everything, some will only do it for system dlls and/or COM interfaces.

Just btw, on 32bit x86, you technically don't have 4gb available in userland apps, its generally 3gb.